# How to insert QWidgets in the middle of a Layout?

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using the Qt framework to build my graphical user interface. I use a **QGridLayout** to position my QWidgets neatly.
The GUI looks like this:

[image]

My application regularly adds new widgets to the GUI at runtime. These new widgets are usually not added at the end of the QLayout, but somewhere in the middle.

The procedure to do this is a bit cumbersome. Applied on the figure above, I would need to take out `widg_C`, `widg_D`, ... from the QGridLayout. Next, I add `widg_x`and `widg_y`, and finally I put the other widgets back again.
This is how I remove widgets from the QGridLayout:

```
for i in reversed(range(myGridLayout.count())):
    self.itemAt(i).widget().setParent(None)
###
```

As long as you're dealing with a small amount of widgets, this procedure is not a disaster. But in my application I display a lot of small widgets - perhaps 50 or more! The application freezes a second while this procedure is ongoing, which is very annoying to the user.
Is there a way to insert widgets somewhere in a QLayout, without the need to take out other widgets?

---

**EDIT:** Apparently the solution for the QVBoxLayout is very simple. Just use the function `insertWidget(..)` instead of `addWidget(..)`. The docs can be found a this link: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#insertWidget 
Unfortunately, I couldn't find a similar function for the QGridLayout.

---

**EDIT:** Many people rightly mentioned that putting back a lot of widgets shouldn't cause a performance issue - it is very fast indeed (thank you @ekhumoro to point that out). Apparently, the performance issue I faced had to do with the algorithm putting the widgets back. It is a fairly complicated recursive algorithm that puts every widget on the right coordinates in the QGridLayout. This resulted in a "flicker" on my display. The widgets are taken out, and put back inside with some delay (due to the algorithm) - causing the flicker.

---

**EDIT:** I found a solution such that I can easily insert new rows into the QGridLayout. Inserting new rows means that I don't need to take out and replace all the widgets from scratch - hence I avoid the expensive recursive algorithm to run.
The solution can be found in my answer below.

Comment: Regarding `QVBoxLayout`, there is the `insertWidget` method, and some similar questions.

Comment: I think you have chosen a wrong model for your GUI. For such dynamic content you might use `QTableWidget`, for instance. It will take care of all items insertions/deletions etc.

Comment: There must be a problem with your code for inserting a widget, because 50 widgets is a trivial number. I did some testing and it takes less than half a second to insert a widget at the top of a layout containing 2000 widgets and move all the others down.

Comment: @ekhumoro I think it depends on how much work is done in the resizeEvent() of the widgets. From memory I seem to recall that Qt generates internal "Layout changed" events whenever you change anything. These end up as calls to resizeEvent() on the widgets (or possibly just calls to moveEvent()). In any case, if you have significant code in those it is going to cause performance problems.

Comment: @StuartFisher. That all falls under what I meant by: "a problem with your code". The OP needs to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the behaviour, otherwise the question is moot.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I think I found a good workaround (see my answer below). @ekhumoro : I don't know where the performance issue actually comes from. The application is quite big..

Comment: In reproducing the performance issue, it doesn't matter how big your application is because it literally takes 30 lines of Python code to presumably do what you want to do and that's all the code you need to presumably demonstrate it. But you still haven't told us how you remove and reinsert those widgets! Once you show how you do it, it'll be easy for someone (e.g. myself) to fix it so that it's fast. Help us help you! Minimization is an art, and if you haven't mastered it, you'll be wasting lots of time over the years.

Comment: I'm sorry @KubaOber . I have made some changes to provide more details. I've also figured out a solution that works very well for me. This solution is posted in my answer below. I hope it can be useful for people with similar issues who bump into this question :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you @ekhumoro, @Stuart Fisher, @vahancho and @mbjoe for your help. I eventually found a way to solve the issue. I no longer use the `QGridLayout()`. Instead, I built a wrapper around the `QVBoxLayout` to behave as if it was a GridLayout, with an extra function to insert new rows:

```
class CustomGridLayout(QVBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomGridLayout, self).__init__()
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)  # !!!
        self.setSpacing(20)


    def addWidget(self, widget, row, col):
        # 1. How many horizontal layouts (rows) are present?
        horLaysNr = self.count()

        # 2. Add rows if necessary
        if row < horLaysNr:
            pass
        else:
            while row >= horLaysNr:
                lyt = QHBoxLayout()
                lyt.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
                self.addLayout(lyt)
                horLaysNr = self.count()
            ###
        ###

        # 3. Insert the widget at specified column
        self.itemAt(row).insertWidget(col, widget)

    ''''''

    def insertRow(self, row):
        lyt = QHBoxLayout()
        lyt.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.insertLayout(row, lyt)

    ''''''

    def deleteRow(self, row):
        for j in reversed(range(self.itemAt(row).count())):
            self.itemAt(row).itemAt(j).widget().setParent(None)
        ###
        self.itemAt(row).setParent(None)

    def clear(self):
        for i in reversed(range(self.count())):
            for j in reversed(range(self.itemAt(i).count())):
                self.itemAt(i).itemAt(j).widget().setParent(None)
            ###
        ###
        for i in reversed(range(self.count())):
            self.itemAt(i).setParent(None)
        ###

    ''''''
```